# Upload Excel file Google Drive API

Tags: php, excel, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, google-api-php-client

I am using Google Drive API to upload Excel files. I did the API connection correctly. Create a folder and upload the excel file correctly. I can see both of them in my google drive. But, the excel file is empty.. What am I missing here?

my code is below:

```
$path = "uploads/school_info.xlsx"; //file that I am uploading, inside a folder of my website.
$folder_id = create_folder("School_".$_POST['submit_uid'], "****folder-id****");
$file_name = "School 1";
$success = insert_file_to_drive( $path, $file_name, $folder_id);

// This will insert file into drive and returns boolean values.
function insert_file_to_drive( $file_path, $file_name, $parent_file_id = null ) {
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive( $GLOBALS['client'] );
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    
    $file->setName( $file_name );
    
    if( !empty( $parent_file_id ) ){
        $file->setParents( [ $parent_file_id ] );
    }
    
    $result = $service->files->create(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            //'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', //works but still empty excel
        )
    );
    
    $is_success = false;
    
    if( isset( $result['name'] ) && !empty( $result['name'] ) ){
        $is_success = true;
    }
    
    return $is_success;
}
```

Comment: Have you opened the file in Google Drive to check that it is really empty? I want to know if you are not uploading it properly, or if you are not getting the data when calling it from php.

Comment: Yes, I tried to open it and says something like:: The file could not be previewed. You may be offline or have limited connectivity. Try download..Thus, it does not open actually to see the rows and columns..
Don't know if that helps.. The excel file is already uploaded in my website and I give this path. Excel already have some rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found what was the problem. As I wrote in my code above, I had a relative path

```
$path = "uploads/school_info.xlsx";
```

when I changed it to full path  like this:

```
$path = "https://www.example.com/uploads/school_info.xlsx";
```

everything works as expected

thank you all for your time

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I have successfully uploaded a `.xlsx` file with the following code. Apparently it is very similar to yours, I just change the `mimeType` and add the `uploadType`. Once the file is uploaded, from the UI version of Drive, I can access and view the contents of the file. In case it still fails, please repeat the process by downloading a sample file from [here](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/).

### Code

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('test.xlsx');
$data = file_get_contents('file_example_XLSX_50.xlsx');
 
$result = $service->files->create($file, array(
   'data' => $data,
   'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
   'uploadType' => 'multipart'
));
```